# Upgrade Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-8

What is the easiest and fastest way to upgrade code from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 7.3 or 8 ? Is there a tool which can do that for me ? How long does it take to do that?

Please help .

Regards

Comment: https://laravelshift.com/ and https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to follow the documentation by laravel, best way is to upgrade to the next version, for example in your situation upgrade to 5.4, when everything is working, and all composer packages are upgraded to the right version, then move on to 5.5 etc...

heres a place to start : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0
and you can just change version in top right corner to get upgrade for the next version.

keep in mind you gonna have to keep upgrading manually packages versions in your **composer.json** to the proper versions, so just analyze the error codes you gonna be getting.

if theres a tool to help with that, then I dont know about it, hopefully next person does.